# Неправильный ответ сервера в responseText

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Когда делаю все с помощью $.ajax ответ всегда правильный

```
success: function(data){
           console.log(data);// `/down/9749.jpg `
         }
```

А когда делаю всё без помощи jquery

```
xml.onload = function(){
        console.log(xml.responseText);// ` `
    }
```

Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Надо дождаться завершения запроса

```
xml.onload = function() {
    if (xml.readyState == 4 && (~~(xml.status / 100)) == 2) {
        console.log(xml.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: С if (xml.readyState === 4 && xml.status=== 200) все также

Comment: @TANKIST тогда смотрите заголовки, может вы передаёте заголовок какой. Или код ответа не 200.

Answer (score 0):

Если данные не текстовые, а бинарные — это, скорее всего, нормально. Причина проста — в JavaScript до последнего времени не было типа для хранения бинарных данных, а тип String для такой цели *принципиально* не предназначены. В итоге, XMLHTTPRequest «сломан» by design. Он пытается декодировать входящие данные как текст, в результате чего получается несколько не то, что, казалось бы, ожидалось.

jQuery «под капотом» использует или интерфейс с ArrayBuffer из XMLHTTPRequest 2 или хак для перекодировки данных из «испорченно» псевдо-Unicode строки в вид, который должен быть исходным. Оба метода описаны [на MDN в статье про прием и передачу бинарных данных](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data).

**Upd:** А, нет, похоже дело не в этом, я сразу не так понял, но у Вас там, вроде бы, строка с именем файла, а не его содержимым. Если и с ожиданием завершения результат неправильный, тогда, пожалуй, для изучения ситуации откройте отладчик (Firebug или еще какой inspector) и посмотрите чем различаются запросы и ответы на них.